# Function similar to erf that is fast at scale and allows for changing the slope at 0?

Tags: numerical-analysis

I'm interested in a function that would allow me to weight my system similar to using the error function; however computing the error function at scale would be a bottleneck. Is there something like erf, but that is much faster to compute and with the following properties?

Given any value [-inf, inf], returns an output in the range [-1, 1], goes through (0,0), and allows me change the slope at (0,0) to tune into my system.

I was considering a Hermitian  polynomial, but then I would be constrained within a certain domain...

Comment: Perhaps some of the functions listed in this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t%28x%29.svg) on are useful (from the Wikipeda article on the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)). You could raise them to diferent powers to adjust their slope.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for, thanks for the input. Feel free to make your comment an answer if you want.

Comment: Great, I've added my comment as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), i.e., functions with an 'S'-shape. Some examples besides the error function are 
$\tanh(x)$, $\arctan{x}$, $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ and $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, which are illustrated in [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t%28x%29.svg).

With approriate scaling and an offset, they can all go through $(0,0)$ and have a range of $(-1,1)$. An easy way to control their slope at $x = 0$ is to introduce a change of variable $x \to \lambda x$.